# Using a web-crawler to search website for occurrences of keywords

Tags: list-manipulation, data, web-access

Given this list of cities:

```
cities = {"Al-Safira", "Al-Nabk", "Qatana", "Al-Qutayfah", "Al-Tall", 
   "Yabrud", "Zabadani", "Izra", "Al-Sanamayn", "Hama", "Masyaf", 
   "Mudardeh", "Salamiyah", "Al-Suqalaybiyah", "Homs", "Al-Mukharram",
    "Palmyra", "Al-Qusayr", "Talkalakh", "Idlib", "Arihah", 
   "Jisr al-Shugur", "Latakia", "Al-Haffah", "Jableh", "Qardaha", 
   "Quneitra", "As-Suwayda", "Salkhad", "Shahba", "Tartus", "Baniyas",
    "Duraykish", "Safita", "Al-Shaykh Badr", "Atarib", 
   "South Mount Simeon", "Abu Kamal", "Mayadin", "Al-Rastan", "Harem",
    "Ma'arrat al-Numan", "Fiq", "Al-Bab", "Dayr Hafir", "Jarabulus", 
   "Manbij", "Al-Raqqah", "Tell Abyad", "Al-Tharwah", "Afrin", 
   "Ayn Al-Arab", "Al-Malikiyah", "Ra's al-'Ayn", 
   "South Mount Simeon", "North Mount Simeon", "Aleppo", "Azaz", 
   "Darayya", "Duma", "Qudsaya", "Markaz Rif Dimashq", "Daraa", 
   "Deir ez-Zor", "Al-Hasakah", "Al Qamishli"};
```

Can I create a *web-crawler* to search on [bbc.co.uk/news](http://www.bbc.co.uk/news) in order to produce a table which shows how many times each city is mentioned on their website?

Comment: It is within the capabilities of Mathematica to do this, some might suggest that there are other environments in which this task might be easier. This choice would depend on your skill set.

Comment: Could you perhaps suggest the easiest platform to do this?

Comment: @Öskå No, it is not.

Comment: No, it's 'not a must have'. Apologies for the confusion.

Comment: Did you manage it? :/

Comment: @Öskå Sorting by date is not necessary. ;)

Comment: @user3482534 Using a professional service for this might be a good idea, costs a little bit though if you crawl more than 10000 pages: http://80legs.com/

Comment: If python is your thing, then scapy would work well.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Warning**: Composed cities/regions like `"South Mount Simeon"` have to be checked. I assume that it searches for `"South"`, `"Mount"` as well so it was yielding huge numbers. I changed them to `"South+Mount+Simeon"`

```
todaysDate = {"2014", "05", "21"};
fromDate = {"2011", "01", "01"};
cities = {"Al-Safira", "Al-Nabk", "Qatana", "Al-Qutayfah", "Al-Tall", 
   "Yabrud", "Zabadani", "Izra", "Al-Sanamayn", "Hama", "Masyaf", 
   "Mudardeh", "Salamiyah", "Al-Suqalaybiyah", "Homs", "Al-Mukharram",
    "Palmyra", "Al-Qusayr", "Talkalakh", "Idlib", "Arihah", 
   "Jisr+al-Shugur", "Latakia", "Al-Haffah", "Jableh", "Qardaha", 
   "Quneitra", "As-Suwayda", "Salkhad", "Shahba", "Tartus", "Baniyas",
    "Duraykish", "Safita", "Al-Shaykh+Badr", "Atarib", 
   "South+Mount+Simeon", "Abu+Kamal", "Mayadin", "Al-Rastan", "Harem",
    "Ma'arrat+al-Numan", "Fiq", "Al-Bab", "Dayr+Hafir", "Jarabulus", 
   "Manbij", "Al-Raqqah", "Tell+Abyad", "Al-Tharwah", "Afrin", 
   "Ayn+Al-Arab", "Al-Malikiyah", "Ra's+al-'Ayn", 
   "South+Mount+Simeon", "North+Mount+Simeon", "Aleppo", "Azaz", 
   "Darayya", "Duma", "Qudsaya", "Markaz+Rif+Dimashq", "Daraa", 
   "Deir+ez-Zor", "Al-Hasakah", "Al-Qamishli"};
```

After checking [www.bbc.co.uk/news](http://www.bbc.co.uk/news) one can find that the following syntax leads to a search query:

```
raw[city_] := 
  Import["http://www.bbc.co.uk/search/news/?q=" <> city <> 
  "&sort=date&start_day=" <> fromDate[[3]] <> "&start_month=" <> 
  fromDate[[2]] <> "&start_year=" <> fromDate[[1]] <> "&end_day=" <> 
  todaysDate[[3]] <> "&end_month=" <> todaysDate[[2]] <> 
  "&end_year=" <> todaysDate[[1]], "Text"]
```

Digging a little into `raw@cities[[1]]` shows:

> `News<span> (5)</span></a>`

Thus the following works:

```
rawCities = raw /@ cities;
occurences[feed_] :=
  ToExpression@
    StringReplace[
     First@StringSplit[
       Extract[StringSplit@feed, 
         First@First@Position[StringPosition[StringSplit@feed, "News<span>"], 
       List[List[__]]] + 1], ")"], "(" | "," -> ""]
occurences[rawCities[[15]]]
```

> ```
> 1138
> ```

```
occurences /@ rawCities
Thread[{cities, occurences /@ rawCities}] // Short
```

> ```
> {5, 0, 6, 0, 0, 1, 48, 1, 1, 450, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1138, 0, 11, 1, 1, 359,
> 0, 0, 202, 0, 3, 3, 10, 0, 0, 0, 39, 72, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 14, 4, 5, 21,
> 0, 0, 14, 0, 0, 1, 0, 3, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 827, 25, 27, 145, 6, 0,
> 30, 6, 1, 0}
>
> {{Al-Safira, 5},{Al-Nabk, 0},<<62>>,{Al-Hasakah, 1},{Al-Qamishli, 0}}
> ```

---

Following the same idea, one could wonder how many times "string" appears on [mathematica.stackexchange.com](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/search?q=string)¹

```
wordQ = "string";
mmaQueryString = 
  Import["https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/search?q=" <> wordQ, "Text"];
```

At some point `mmaQueryString` shows:

> ```
>     <h2>
>         1,692 <span class="results-label">results</span>
>     </h2>
> ```

Then the following works:

```
Extract[StringSplit@mmaQueryString, 
  First@First@
    Position[StringPosition[StringSplit[mmaQueryString], "results-label"], 
     List[List[__]]] - 2]
```

> ```
> "1,693"
> ```

¹ It only works for words that don't belong to [tags](/questions/tagged/tags)